# Prove a logarithmic statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I don't quite know where to start, i would start with the RHS of the statement if i could but that's probably not allowed, is it?

Comment: If you could start with the RHS, then what would be your approach?

Comment: Hint:  $\log_a b = c \iff a^c =b$.  And $\log_{\frac 1a}=\frac 1b \iff (\frac 1a)^c = \frac 1b$.

Comment: Alternatively prove that $(\frac 1a)^{\log_a b} =\frac 1b$.  If you can do that then *by definition* $\log_{\frac 1a}\frac 1b$ will have to be $\log_a b$.  (Hint:  $(\frac 1k)^x = \frac 1{k^x}$ and Hint:  $m^{\log_m n} = n$.)

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of a logarithm if $z=\log_{\frac{1}a}\frac{1}b$, then
$$
\big(\frac{1}{a}\big)^z=\frac{1}b.
$$
This is equivalent to $a^z=b$, which again by the definition of a logarithm,
means that $z=\log_a(b)$. Thus, $\log_a(b)=z=\log_{\frac{1}a}\frac{1}b$.